# Build ActionScript Native Extension

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'am trying to build an ANE, 
this is my extension.xml

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
<id>com.skunk.nativelibrary</id>
<versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
  <platforms>
    <platform name="Android-ARM">
      <applicationDeployment>
        <nativeLibrary>boot.jar</nativeLibrary>
        <initializer>com.skunk.startonboot.NativeLibraryExtension</initializer>
        <finalizer>com.skunk.startonboot.NativeLibraryExtension</finalizer>
      </applicationDeployment>
    </platform>
  </platforms>
</extension>
```

I call it this way on the Flex Library Project :

```
context = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("com.skunkkk.nativelibrary", null);
```

I have a folder containing those doc :

- Boot.jar ( the native part )
- The extension.xml file
- The SWC from the Flex Library Project
- The SWF extarcted from the last file
- The .P12 keyFile

Finally I run this on the cmd :

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -storepass [keyPassWord] -keystore skunkkk.p12 -tsa none -target ane StartOnBoot.ane extension.xml -swc SkunKNativeLibrary.swc -platform Android-ARM library.swf boot.jar
```

What could possibly be wrong ? Thank you !

---

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.snowflax.com/native-imei-action-script-extension-for-android/) just to see, created an ANE with his source code, My application crashes when using it ...

---

I don't know if I need a compatibility configuration for the ANE, anyway, I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6, Flex SDK 4.6.0, AIR 3.1, Eclipse Kepler and testing on Android 4.1.2

Comment: I think you have to tell us what could be wrong because we can help you with the "Why" it may be wrong.  Are you receiving errors when you build that from the command line?  OR are the errors from your Flex project?  Or is there some other issue?

Comment: @Reboog711 The issue is that this ANE makes the application starts on the os satrtup, the other part is fine( I mean the native side ), pretty sure with that, and when the device starts, I just receive "Unfortunately the application ... stopped", so I thought that the listeners cant find the receivers, which is because I may have done something wrong while building this, ...

Comment: @Reboog711 I'm pretty sure I'm not reaching the receiver, I have tested with total random wrong values (on the listener in the manifest) and still got the same error when I restart the device,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running a wrong command, this is how it worked :

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore FILE_KEY_NAME.p12 -storepass FILE_KEY_PASSWORD -target ane LIBRARY_NAME.ane extension.xml -swc SWC_FILE_NAME.swc -platform Android-ARM -C android_lib_dir .
```

Of course, I have the library.swf and NATIVEPROJECT.jar inside the directory `android_lib_dir`

May be someone will face the same problem,